# Selecting from spinner and clicking a button to open a new activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, spinner

How can i start a new activity with a button when i select from a spinner? 
my code tho.. i've searched a lot but nothing works, hope something happens here :)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgbtnarroceros);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    Spinner spinner;
    spinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner) ;
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.itinerary, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item) ;
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, you want to open an activity which has a button when you select an item from the spinner. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

setOnItemSelectedListener to your spinner and handle the item select event.

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                               switch(position){
                                                  case 0:
                                                            //start activity on selection of any item you want, here I am assuming first item.
                                                            Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, ActivityWithButton.class);
                                                            startActivity(intent);
                                                            break;


                                                     }        
                                         }

                                         @Override
                                         public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                                         }
                                     });
```

Comment: At last! thanks man :) uhm... but why does it starts with the second class and not the main ? i have to press the back button to go back to my spinner and choose again even though in my manifest my launcher is the main   :/